# 'No X11 DISPLAY variable was set' trying to run Minecraft server on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, minecraft, x11, x11-forwarding

I run into the following issue when I try running a minecraft server on an ec2 instance:

```
java[7261]: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
java[7261]: at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
java[7261]: at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
java[7261]: at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
java[7261]: at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
java[7261]: at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1763)
java[7261]: at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1838)
java[7261]: at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1696)
java[7261]: at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:863)
java[7261]: at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:666)
java[7261]: at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:637)
java[7261]: at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.launchGui(SimpleInstaller.java:177)
java[7261]: at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.main(SimpleInstaller.java:147)
systemd[1]: minecraft.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: Unit minecraft.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: minecraft.service failed.
```

my user data script looks like this (run every time an instance is started):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo yum -y install java-1.8.0
sudo mkdir /minecraft
sudo chown -R 777 /minecraft
cd /minecraft
aws s3 cp s3://minecraft-server-v3/setup/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860-installer.jar /minecraft/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860-installer.jar
export DISPLAY=:0.0
java -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860-installer.jar --installServer
echo '#By changing the setting below to TRUE you are indicating your agreement to our EULA (https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula).
#Mon Aug 06 18:11:14 UTC 2018
eula=true' > eula.txt
aws s3 cp s3://minecraft-server-v3/setup/mods.zip /minecraft/mods.zip
unzip mods.zip
sudo aws s3 cp s3://minecraft-server-v3/setup/minecraft.service /etc/systemd/system/minecraft.service
sudo chmod 777 /etc/systemd/system/minecraft.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service minecraft start
```

and my `minecraft.service` file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Service
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/minecraft
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx8G -Xms8G -jar /minecraft/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860-installer.jar nogui
```

Any idea what could be going on? Which operation requires a display? I'm very confused. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

From my understanding the issue is with your `minecraft.service` file.

When you are starting the service you are running the installer for the forge server.

The installer requires X unless run with the `--installServer` flag as you have done above in your user data script.

This is why you are experiencing the error.

## The solution

I would imagine that you want to run the actual server .jar

For the version of the installer you are using I'm pretty sure that the name for the jar is:

```
minecraftforge-universal-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar
```

Using this as an example you want to replace your current command with this:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xmx8G -Xms8G -jar minecraftforge-universal-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui
```

Comment: Oh my god, great catch. Thank you so much!! This got me past the X11 errors (still hitting errors starting the server with the 2860 jar file :(